# Accessing other siblings in Particular row using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have series of li in a ul . and they all set as display:inline-block for a continuous flow.

[Codepen Link here](http://codepen.io/swapnaranjitanayak/pen/MyzQJO).

Whenever I will hover over any li in ul , I am able to get index value of it.

**What I want** : I want to access other li index value , presented in same row. for e.g If I am on li having index value  1, I want to access  index value 0 , 2, 3 of same row.  At the same time , for window width below , I would like to access only index value 0 item in row , as below 500px , I am showing two items in a row.

**HTML**

```
<ul>
<li></li>
<li></li>
<li></li>
<li></li>
<li></li>
<li></li>
<li></li>
<li></li>
<li></li>
<li></li>
</ul>
```

**css:**

```
    ul{
  list-style:none;
}
li{
  width:20%;
  height: 80px;
  background-color: red;
  display:inline-block;
}
@media (max-width:500px){
 li{
      width:40%;
 }
}
```

**JS:**

```
$( "ul li" )
      .mouseover(function() {
        alert($( this ).index());
      })
      .mouseout(function() {

    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$( "ul li" )
      .mouseover(function() {
  var li=$(this);
  var ul=li.parent('ul');
  var noOflis=$( "ul li" ).length;
  var clickedIndex=li.index();

  var windowWidth=window.innerWidth;
    if(windowWidth>500){
      //var noOfRows=noOflis/4;
      var clickedrow=Math.floor(clickedIndex/4)+1;
      console.log("Clicked row "+clickedrow);
      for(var i=0;i<4;i++){
        var index=((clickedrow-1)*4)+i;
        if(index<noOflis){
          console.log(index);
          //Here you get the index for large screen
        }

      }

    }else{
      //var noOfRows=noOflis/4;
      var clickedrow=Math.floor(clickedIndex/2)+1;
      console.log("Clicked row "+clickedrow);
      for(var i=0;i<2;i++){
        var index=((clickedrow-1)*2)+i;
        if(index<noOflis){
          console.log(index);
          //Here you get the index for small screen
        }

      }
    }

      })
      .mouseout(function() {

    });
```

Please have a look the code above.

[Here is a link to the Codepen](http://codepen.io/swagatswain/pen/ozapvY?editors=1111)

Answer (score 1):

This code lists all the `li` elements in the row clicked.  It checks the `top` of each element against the `top` of the one clicked.

It is really klunky code.   Are you sure you need to do this?

```
  $("ul li").mouseover(function () {
        var $Clicked = $(this);

        console.log($Clicked.index());

        // previous items in row
        var $Temp = $Clicked;
        while ($Temp.prev().length == 1) 
        {
            $Temp = $Temp.prev();

            if ($Temp.position().top == $Clicked.position().top) {
                console.log($Temp.index());
            }
            else
                break;
        }

        // next items in row
        var $Temp = $Clicked;
        while ($Temp.next().length == 1) 
        {
            $Temp = $Temp.next();

            if ($Temp.position().top == $Clicked.position().top) {
                console.log($Temp.index());
            }
            else
                break;
        }
    });
```

As a simpler alternative, you could just iterate ALL the `li` elements.  Any element with a matching `top` is in the row.